# Why are the < turned into &lt;?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Im trying to replace the html of emoticon (the image) in to plain text. But I need normal HTML to show.

On here: http://jsfiddle.net/xk2VX/

Im using:

```
$("code").each(function() {
    var a = ['<img class="smile" src="http://static.yamma.org/images/icons/smile.png">', '&lt;img class="laugh" src="http://static.yamma.org/images/icons/laugh.png"&gt;'],
        b = [":)", ":D"];

    for (var d = 0; d < a.length; d++) {
        var e = $(this).html(),
            f = e,
            g = f.indexOf(a[d]);
        while (g != -1) {
            f = f.replace(a[d], b[d]);
            g = f.indexOf(a[d]);
        }
        $(this).text(f);
    }
});​
```

And it returns: `&lt;div&gt;Hi&lt;/div&gt; :) :D :) :D`;
but it should return: `<div>Hi</div> :) :D :) :D`;

I just don't get why the `<` and `>` are being replaced with `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Is there a fix for this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I notice that you're calling `.text()` at the end of your for loop when you should be calling `.html()` instead, even though you correctly call `.html()` at the beginning:

```
    for (var d = 0; d < a.length; d++) {
        var e = $(this).html(),
            f = e,
            g = f.indexOf(a[d]);
        while (g != -1) {
            f = f.replace(a[d], b[d]);
            g = f.indexOf(a[d]);
        }
        $(this).text(f);
    }
```

`.text()` always converts HTML special characters to entities so they won't be treated as markup, because it expects *text*, not *HTML*.

Comment: .html() renders the code though. So <div>Hi</div> just turns into Hi. I need it to display as: <div>Hi</div>

Comment: Shouldn't the browser display it that way with `.text()` then? Or perhaps there's some double encoding going on with your `<code>` tags...

Comment: thats the problem. and thats why I posted this, for help.

Answer (score 0):

It does help to read the API at times: http://api.jquery.com/text/#text2 - when calling `.text()`,

> replaces special characters with their HTML entity equivalents

So, like @BoltClock says, you're using the wrong method for what you're trying to do.

Comment: .html() renders the code though. So <div>Hi</div> just turns into Hi. I need it to display as: <div>Hi</div>

Comment: that doesn't fix anything (i tryed)